# How can I sort the querystring by key?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing, query-string

I'm using ASP.NET MVC4. How do I sort the querystring shown in the browser?

Instead of: `...?c=1&b=1&a=1`
I want:       `...?a=1&b=1&c=1`

If the querystring is based on a link which I create, then I can sort it easily by sorting the `RouteValueDictionary`. But if the querystring comes from a submitted form, then I noticed that its ordering is based on the order of the form's `<input>` and `<select>` fields. Since the markup changes often, I don't want to manually sort it this way though.

So I hope I can sort the `RouteValueDictionary` from which these routes come from. But I don't know how?

Comment: If you're wondering why even bother, it's because different things on a view add to the querystring, and it becomes a mess. I want to keep it sorted for consistency - if for no other reason than it makes it easy for me to see what's going on and track bugs.

Comment: How do you get this url? Could you show code that redirect you to this url.

Comment: @KirillBestemyanov: Any form which is posted and then the results shown in a view (nothing fancy going on). But the order will be dictated by the order of the form's fields in the markup. I want to set the order myself somehow, by intercepting the `RouteValuesDictionary`, if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does not appear that this is possible with MVC4.

Answer (score 0):

if the query string is generated based on the order which the inputs/elements appear in the form, short of either fudging around with the form to make things 'appear' in the order you want whilst maintaining their alphabetical order in the markup, you could catch the submit yourself on the client, strip the form down and redirect to the url setting the querystring yourself.
but that would seem completely bonkers to me, better to find some other way to check for bugs than trawling the qs, maybe just add a alphabetised dump of the qs at the top of the page whilst you are debugging

Comment: Yes I thought of that, and yes you're right it's a waste of time. But there must be some way to intercept the `RouteValueDictionary` before it is sent to the view engine. Though even if there is, it might be even more complicated, and more of a waste of time. Want to know for sure though.